# How does this basic reimplementation of strlen() find the length?

Tags: c, string, strcmp, strcpy, strcat

My professor showed us this sample implementation of a function to find the length of a string, saying that this is how you would do it without actually using the `strlen()` function:

```
int length(char word)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; word[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        {

        }
    }
    return i;
 }
```

She said it would be in our best interest for us to do similarly for `strcat()` , `strcmp()`, and `strcpy()`, to understand how the functions actually work.

What is going on in this function? Is there anything I can learn from this example to help me reimplement the other three?

Comment: I guess the idea is that trying to implement these function gives you a deeper understanding in strings and what these functions do. Why not just try to write some code - i.e. learn

Comment: You *seem* to be asking if it's worth your while to re-implement library functions to learn how they work. Yes. Yes it is. In real code, however, you would use the standard functions.

Comment: Your teacher gave you the answer to the question *How would you implement a string length function without using `strlen`* (which is a good example, by the way, besides the syntactically redundant empty braces), and she has asked that you do something similar with `strcat`, `strcat`, and `strcmp`. Start by trying to understand how the `length` function works that she gave. Then take a stab at one or more of the others and come back to SO with questions about your attempted implementation. The functions use elementary C programming concepts that you need to try and understand and work through.

Comment: @ooga: for beginners, true. But I write derivatives of the standard string functions for "real code" all the time. Not all you can possibly do with strings is covered with `<string.h>`.

Comment: @Jongware I agree, absolutely. But when the standard functions fit they are preferred.

Comment: BTW you have a typo in the function you're showing. It should be `int length(char *word)`.

Comment: FYI this version has a serious bug: if you pass it a string longer than `INT_MAX`, it will invoke undefined behavior via (signed) integer overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be asking multiple questions, I'll attempt to answer your first one.

Your function above is not valid, it will not compile, or work.

Here's an implementation of `strlen`.

```
size_t strlen(char s[])
{
    size_t i;

    i = 0;
    while (s[i]= != '\0') //loop over the array, if null is seen, break
        ++i;
    return i; // return length (without null)

}
```

In regards to the explanation, `strings` in C are represented as an array of characters. There has to a logical way to denote the end of a string, which in our case is the null character `\0`. Be careful with this, strings require `n+1` storage, most implementations of `strlen` return the length of the string *excluding* the null character.

You may be wondering what `\0` represents, in C the null character represents a character constant, the value in ASCII is 0. You could write 0, instead `\0` is added to emphasize the nature of the string.

Again, another implementation of `strlen` using pointer arithmetic

```
size_t strlen(char *s)
{
    char *p = s;
    while (*p != '\0')
        ++p;
    return p - s; //use ptrdiff_t or size_t?
}
```

Also, strcat for good measure.

```
void strcat(char s[], char t[])
{
    int j, k;

    j = k = 0;
    while (s[j] != '\0') // are we at the end of s? 
        ++i;
    while ((s[j++] = t[k++]) != '\0') // copy t to s 
        ; // null statement
}
```

*the library implementations returns a pointer to the string, not void; see man 3 `strcat`*

In `strcat`, a character is copied (sequentially) from `t` to  the end of `s`. A common C idiom, is to increment the stepper variable in the loop. As each character is copied, the stepper variable is incremented to be in place for the next character.

A `void` return value may be used, due the internal representation of arrays in C as pointers (return by reference.)

A *devastating* bug in this implementation is we assume `s` is big enough to hold all of `s  + t + 1`.  In the interest of brevity, I ignored this issue.

Comment: That's code our professor gave us -_- yea it hasn't be compiling and i've been trying to attempt to do the other 3 functions like that and it hasn't been working lol

Comment: @user3264742 You're just missing the asterisk before `word` to make it compile.

Comment: Implementing functions such as `atoi` or a basic version of the unix `grep` are really good exercises. I enjoyed the exercises in K&R on implementing unix tools quite a lot.

Comment: Indeed. K&R, while claiming to be a reference manual, remains one of the finest tutorial books I've ever read.

Comment: lrobb, reimplementing basic shell programs like `grep` or `ls` may be a nightmare, until student opens the source code of busybox...

Comment: @osgx I can understand 90% of coreutils after a few hundred hours of using C. Although, I'd highly recommend K&R for the OP, most of the library functions are explained in detail.

Comment: Consider the C specified signature of `size_t strlen(const char *s);`

Comment: @chux - Yes, I ignored the standard library to implementation to write a basic answer. I'll edit my answer with the standard library implementation, with `ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: @lrobb  Code is missing the proper use of `const` in the functions and I suspect you want `p`, not `w`.

Comment: Note `char *strcat(char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2);` returns `char *`, not `void`

Comment: @chux - are we taking a top level const and a low level const?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51507/discussion-between-lrobb-and-chux)

Comment: @user3264742 If my answer helped you, press to accept button (green tick) to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to strlen, it is traversing the char array, finding the first null byte.

```
size_t length( const char * word)
{
    size_t i = 0; // Counter

    while(word[i] != '\0') // Compare current position to null 
    { 
        i++;
    }

    return i; // Return position.
}
```

Comment: The proper signature is `size_t length(const char *str)`.

Comment: As you are already incrementing `i`, there is no need to increment `*word` as well. `word[i]`, as suggested in the OP's snippet, will work just as good.

Comment: @Jongware But `word[i]` also incurs an addition, so it's not really any more efficient.

Comment: Consider `length("")` and fix the code.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to know *What is a string in C?*. A string is an array of non-zero bytes (`char`), usually printable characters, which terminate in a null (zero, represented by the character `'\0'`).

Then, you need to know how a `for` loop works:

```
for ( initial condition ; test condition ; loop expression )
{
    // some code
}
// Code after the loop
```

The `for` loop will:

1. Execute *initial condition*
2. Execute *test condition* and, if it's TRUE (non-zero) will execute *some code*. Otherwise, if it's FALSE (zero) it will EXIT the loop and go to the *Code after the loop*.
3. Execute *loop expression*
4. Go to 2

With the basics out of the way, let's look at the function given by the teacher:

```
int length(char *word)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        {

        }
    }

    return i;
 }
```

The meat of the function is the `for` loop: It then goes through the `for` loop steps:

1. Initially, `i` is set to `0`. `i` represents the index into the string (array of `char`).
2. Check if `word[i] != '\0'` (in other words, if this is TRUE, then it's not the end of the string). There's no code inside the loop to execute, so we go right to step 3.
3. The *loop expression* is executed, which is incrementing `i`, the string (`char` array) index, meaning we are now pointing to the next character in the string.

If your word is, "cat", then the array is `{ 'c', 'a', 't', '\0' }`. So the loop steps will do this:

1. Set `i` to `0`.
2. Check `word[0] != '\0'`, which checks `'c' != '\0'`. This is TRUE because `'c'` is NOT equal to `'\0'`.
3. Take `i++` (increment `i`), so now `i` is `1`.
4. Check `word[1] != '\0'`, which checks `'a' != '\0'`. This is TRUE because `'a'` is NOT equal to `'\0'`.
5. Take `i++` (increment `i`), so now `i` is `2`.
6. Check `word[2] != '\0'`, which checks `'t' != '\0'`. This is TRUE because `'t'` is NOT equal to `'\0'`.
7. Take `i++` (increment `i`), so now `i` is `3`.
8. Check `word[3] != '\0'`, which checks `'\0' != '\0'`. This is FALSE because `'\0'` is equal to `'\0'`.
9. The loop ends now because the *test condition* has become FALSE.

What's the value of `i` at the end of the loop? It's `3`, which is the length of the string because we kept stepping through the string, one character at a time, incrementing `i` from `0` until we hit the spot after the last character of the string, which is `'\0'`.

The function then returns `i`, the length of the string.

HTH